# How can I create mallet instance from feature value object?

Tags: mallet

I have a `json` object like

```
{"f1": 2.1, "f2": 3.2, "f3": 1234.12, "label": "GOOD"}
```

I want to convert it into `mallet` instance

Answer (score 0):

To do this within java would require parsing JSON and constructing Mallet instances. I find java JSON parsing difficult because the language wants to have types for every object.

I would personally suggest converting the JSON file into the "svmlight" format accepted by Mallet, using a python script or similar.